# DB2 For i - CREATE TRIGGER - SQL0206 - Column or global variable not found

Tags: database, triggers, db2-400

**Request:**

Please explain why the CREATE TRIGGER statement throws

> SQL0206 - Column or global variable PACKED_FLD not found

**Sample Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE TST_TABLE ( 
  CHAR_FLD_ALIAS   FOR COLUMN CHAR_FLD   CHAR(9) CCSID 37 NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  PACKED_FLD_ALIAS FOR COLUMN PACKED_FLD DECIMAL(9, 0)    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  ZONED_FLD_ALIAS  FOR COLUMN ZONED_FLD  NUMERIC(9, 0)    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , 
  DATE_FLD_ALIAS   FOR COLUMN DATE_FLD   DATE             NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, 
  TIME_FLD_ALIAS   FOR COLUMN TIME_FLD   TIME             NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME, 
  TSTAMP_FLD_ALIAS FOR COLUMN TSTAMP_FLD TIMESTAMP        NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
PRIMARY KEY( CHAR_FLD_ALIAS ) )

CREATE TRIGGER TST_TRGPGM_LONG_NAME  
  NO CASCADE                        
  BEFORE INSERT ON TST_TABLE       
  REFERENCING OLD AS o NEW AS n     
  FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2ROW          
  PROGRAM NAME TST_TRGPGM            
  BEGIN                                                       
    SET n.PACKED_FLD = 999;          
  END
```

**Complete Error Message:**

> Message ID . . . . . . :   SQL0206
>   Severity . . . . . . . :   30
>   Message type . . . . . :   Diagnostic
>
> Message . . . . :   Column or global variable PACKED_FLD not found.
>   Cause . . . . . :   PACKED_FLD was not found as a column of table *N
>   in *N and   was not found as a global variable in *N. If the table is
>   *N, PACKED_FLD is    not a column of any table or view that can be referenced.
>
> Recovery  . . . :   Do one of the following and try the request again:
>       - Ensure that the column and table names are specified correctly in the     statement.
>       - If this is a SELECT statement, ensure that all the required tables were   named in the FROM clause.
>       - If the column was intended to be a correlated reference, qualify the      column with the correct table designator.
>       - If the column was intended to be a global variable, qualify the name      with the schema where the global variable exists or ensure the schema is in the path.

**Reference Sites:**

- [TechTip: More-Flexible SQL Triggers](http://www.mcpressonline.com/sql/techtip-more-flexible-sql-triggers.html?cm_mc_uid=12840944491714412830229&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1449818534)
- [Multiple event triggers support on IBM DB2 for i](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-event_triggers_support/)
- [IBM Redbook: Stored Procedures, Triggers, and User-Defined Functions on DB2 Universal Database for iSeries](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246503.pdf)
- [IBM Knowledge Center: CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzhctrigger.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try the "long name" and not the "short name", as far as I can re-call,  it references the long name (COLUMN_NAME ) in the SYSCOLUMNS table.

Regards
Roland

Comment: The Shame, The Shame is unbearable.

Comment: @ZS6JCE, don't feel bad.  It's strange that an SQL trigger requires the use of the long name.  I suppose it kind of makes sense.  Inside the trigger you're not dealing with a table.  You're dealing with a buffer of data.  The system only generates one name for the elements.